# Actions on Google coarse location always empty

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have been writing an actions on google app tied into dialog flow with a .net fulfillment back end. My app needs coarse location to function. However in testing the location is always empty when I use the coarse location permission. When I change the permission to precise it sends lat and long back, but when I use coarse it does not send back the address entered in the simulator location box.

Edit: The device type is set to speaker at the top.

Edit2: Added images album 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAZk4.jpg

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code, screen shots of the Intent you think you should be triggered, along with samples of the JSON that you're getting?

Comment: Yes I have added some screens. The thing is all the intents and permissions are working because device precise location works like it should. Its only the coarse location that's empty.

Comment: @JonathanEllis did you ever resolve this as I have the same issue

Comment: @mjroodt no I never did find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#getting_the_results_of_the_helper):

> Currently, precise location only returns lat/lng coordinates on phones
>   and a geocoded address on voice-activated speakers. Coarse location
>   only works on voice-activated speakers.

To make sure you are testing with the speakers in simulation, make sure you have selected that device icon before you invoke the action

[image]

Comment: I have tried it with the simulator set to speaker its still blank device location.